# SQL: How to Consolidate CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have to repeat a CASE statement twice, and I'm wondering if there's a way to consolidate it.

Basically, I have a:

```
where open_time >= '11/1/16' and open_time < '12/1/16'
```

The problem is I need to DATEADD to the open_time based on a CASE Statement.  I don't know how to consolidate it together, so I'm doing it twice.
Like:

```
where
   DATEADD(hh,
      CASE WHEN MONTH(open_time)=1 THEN -5
      ELSE -4
      END
      ,open_time) >= '11/1/16'AND
   DATEADD(hh,
      CASE WHEN MONTH(open_time)=1 THEN -5
      ELSE -4
      END
      ,open_time) < '12/1/16'
```

Is there any way to make it so I don't have to repeat the entire CASE Statment?

Comment: stuff the result of the case into a variable, then use that variable instead?

Comment: I would love to output the result of the case into a variable.  But I'm not sure that will work, since there is a different value for open_time for each row.

Comment: If you own the ETL that builds the table, you could persist that calculation as a column.  You could create a view on top of the table with that calculated field (and others as you need).  If neither of that is an option, you can use a CTE or subquery, but test your performance both ways and stick with the one that performs best.

Comment: Also, you might prefer this shorthand (available on SQL Server 2012 and higher) if none of the above is an option: IIF(MONTH(open_time)=1,-5,-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a BETWEEN?

```
WHERE case ... end BETWEEN '11/1/16' AND '12/1/16'
```

Note that between is "inclusive", so `a between b and c` is `a <= b AND b <= c`.

Comment: I think BETWEEN is the way I'm going to have to go.  I was trying to stay away from it due to the variable nature of the date, but if there's no other way to consolidate the CASE, I'll probably have to.  Thanks.

Comment: `BETWEEN` is not equivalent to the logic in the question.

Comment: are those two days always going to be one month (day?) apart? You could be better off just checking for equality on the year/month part instead of a between. `where (@var = 'ok') or ((year(datefield) = 2016) and (month(datefield) = 11))`-type thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could write this as:

```
where (month(open_time) = 1 and
       cast(dateadd(hour, -5, open_time) as date) between '2016-11-01' and '2016-11-30'
      ) or
      (month(open_time) <> 1 and
       cast(dateadd(hour, -4, open_time) as date) between '2016-11-01' and '2016-11-30'
      )
```

I'm not a fan of using `between` with `date`/`time` values.  In this case, the value is *explicitly* a date, so it doesn't seem too confusing.

Or, if you prefer:

```
      month(open_time) <> 1 and
      cast(dateadd(hour, case when month(open_time) = 1 then -5 else -4 end, open_time
                  ) as date) between '2016-11-01' and '2016-11-30'
```

Comment: of course, if the point is not DRY, now it's repeating a cast, instead of repeating a case.

Comment: The problem is that I greatly simplified the code in my post; this solution would require repeating lots of code, too, just a different part.

Comment: @DonTrembly . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask, not one that you might intend.